# Spark executor is throwing error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to import a table from my oracle database using spark and here I am using Scala to import the table.
My jdbc driver is ojdbc7.jar and it's added in both the parameter spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath in configuration file

`spark.driver.extraClassPath      :/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/s
hare/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.executor.extraClassPath    :/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/s
hare/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native`

I can successfully import the table. I can print the schema of the table. But while performing any operations like Count,show() it throws below error

`

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver 
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.findClass(ParentClassLoader.scala:26)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.loadClass(ParentClassLoader.scala:34)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.loadClass(ParentClassLoader.scala:30)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:77)
>   ... 21 more

`

Comment: Is /home/hadoop/ojdbc7.jar readable on every machine by the user running the executor jvms? It looks like only the driver has the class available.

Comment: Thanks @RickMoritz, Placing the jar in /usr/lib/spark/jars/. solved my problem

Comment: @SurajitKundu Could you answer your question and accept for future readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was because Spark was not able to locate the ojdbc7.jar from every core node. So placing this jar in a shared location like /usr/lib/spark/jars will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do few other things including adding jar file full location as a dependency under spark section in the interpreter as an artifact

If you just want %jdbc to work, update the jdbc section under interpreter, add the jar file full location as a artifact under the dependencies and also update the default.driver, default.url, default.user, default.password accordingly